# Merging Multiple Excel files with more than 1 row of headers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I'm working with uniform Excel files, they all have the same header for the first 4 rows. I only need the 4th row repeated once as a header on the merged file.

I followed a tutorial to merge all the files using Pandas, but it also repeats rows 2-4 which messes up the data. Is there a way for me to tell Pandas to ignore them when concatenating the data?

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
location = '#path/*.xlsx'
excel_files = glob.glob(location)
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
for excel_file in excel_files:
    df2 = pd.read_excel(excel_file)
    df1 = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)
print(df1)
df1.to_excel('#path/excel_file_name.xlsx', index= False)
```

Example of output

```
Col 1   Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5    Col6    Col7    Col8    Col9    Col10   Col11   Col12
                                
Item1   Item2   Item3   Item4   Item5   Item6   Item7   Item8   Item9   Item10  Item11  Item12
#Data From 1st file
Col 1   Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5    Col6    Col7    Col8    Col9    Col10   Col11   Col12
                                                
Item1   Item2   Item3   Item4   Item5   Item6   Item7   Item8   Item9   Item10  Item11  Item12
#Data From 2nd file
Col 1   Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5    Col6    Col7    Col8    Col9    Col10   Col11   Col12
                                                
Item1   Item2   Item3   Item4   Item5   Item6   Item7   Item8   Item9   Item10  Item11  Item12  
#etc
```

EDIT:
So I came a little closer... in my for loop I took @jch idea and added this:

```
    for excel_file in excel_files:
        if excel_files.index(excel_file) ==0:
            df2 = pd.read_excel(excel_file)
        else:
            df2 = pd.read_excel(excel_file, skiprows=4)
```

But that only reads from the first file now. Also, the header of this file looks like

```
Selected Criteria:  Unnamed: 1  Unnamed: 2  Unnamed: 3 Unnamed: 4 ETC...
```

I want to make those "Unnamed Criteria #" blank

Answer (score 0):

Try skipping the first 3 rows to see if that works for you:

```
df2 = pd.read_excel(excel_file, skiprows=3)
```

If not give us some more information - like what you input data looks like and what your expected output should be.

Comment: I just edited it to hopefully give more clarity

Comment: If I am understanding correctly, What you need is for `read_excel` to actually read the headers from each Excel file.  `pd.concat` does not duplicate headers - it handles them (only one copy).  So use `skiprows=` to get to the header you want and do that for every file.  Then `pd.concat` can take it from there.  I am guessing you are trying to just read the header from the first file only.  And not from the subsequent.  Too much work.   Get rid of the `if`.  Of course that is if I understand what you are trying to do.  If that is incorrect, supply examples of input and output should be.

Comment: Is your example of output above the result of your code or your desired state?

Comment: No, the desired would be a row of the column index, a row of the item index, and then all the data. Each file though has those 3 rows of headers.